# About the "personal impact and articulation skills"

Tags: discussion, terminology

Should we drop using that expression?

I was reading the question and the relative answers. What comes out is:

1. It does not exist outside Travel.SE
2. It has been coined on Travel.SE by a user referring to a decade years old document...that does not contain that expression at all (not even all the single words making it)
3. It's used only on Travel.SE, to the point that explanations were needed because most users have no idea of what it means.

What's the point in giving assistance to other people using a non existing, not understandable sentence?

Comment: We? It looks like only one user is using this expression. Perhaps you could join the chat and ask him?

Comment: 'Funds parking' as a term has also been coined on Travel.SE. Doesn't mean we can't use it to describe why a certain visa was refused. Also, 'personal skills' is an extremely generic term, I don't see why we can't use it in appropriate contexts. At the end of the day the concept does exist in real life, the precise choice of words to describe it doesn't matter.

Comment: @MarkMayo it's not about the user, it's about the community. I don't jump on a user myself and ask him to stop doing something, I ask the community to produce some guidelines we all agree to follow. If there is no guideline, why should someone ask someone else to not do something?

Comment: @motoDrizzt Oops, sorry, I didn't mean to ask him NOT to do it, sorry, but to understand why he's using that - you did ask "what's the point .... using" that sentence, so figured he might be able to answer.  Perhaps it's a legally appropriate sentence that is critical to immigration, or perhaps it's not. I'm just hypothesizing here.

Comment: Is there evidence that most people did not understand _personal impact and articulation skills_? My hypothesis is that 90% of people with a knowledge of spoken English and has attended any interview of any sort should know what it means. I was actually very surprised that it came up as a whole question and got so much attention because its a very normal expression. I grew up in Ghana and yet I have known this from my early teens or so.

Comment: I would be delighted to engage with you in chat and hammer out a satisfactory answer to this question.  Indeed if this is disrupting your enjoyment of the site then something should be done about it.

Comment: [Context](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/93939/819). It would be a big improvement to edit a link to this question into the meta question, but I don't have the rep to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I see no reason to stop using the expression. It's perfectly normal English and it seems irrelevant that it's not a phrase used in official documents.